# For loop that doesnt stop

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

SO, Im not sure how to fix this, but I get an infinite loop and cant seem to figureout how to not do that.

```
# user guesses the number. Returns Yes or try again.
import random

# Instruct user to guess a number.
number = int(input("Guess a number, see if you're right."))

rn = random.randint(1,10)

while number != rn:  # User number is not equal to rn then continue.
    print("Sorry. Try again.")

    if number < rn:  # tells player that the number is too low.
        print("Higher")

    if number > rn:  # Tells the player that the number is too high.
        print("Lower")

    if number == rn:  # User number equals random number break
        break

    print("Well, you got it. Congrats!")
```

Comment: You never change the value of `rn` in the loop so you're just checking the same thing over and over. You need your input and the assignment to `rn` inside the loop as well.

Comment: Neither `number` nor `rn` change within the loop, so why *would* it stop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they don't get it right, you need to get a new guess from the user:

```
# user guesses the number. Returns Yes or try again.
import random

# Instruct user to guess a number.
number = int(input("Guess a number, see if you're right."))

rn = random.randint(1,10)

while number != rn:  # User number is not equal to rn then continue.
    print("Sorry. Try again.")

    if number < rn:  # tells player that the number is too low.
        print("Higher")

    if number > rn:  # Tells the player that the number is too high.
        print("Lower")

    # Ask for a new number
    number = int(input("Guess another number."))

# Move this to outside the loop
print("Well, you got it. Congrats!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call input for whenever it doesn't equal **rn**, also put the success before the **break**, else you may not get to it.

```
# user guesses the number. Returns Yes or try again.
import random

# Instruct user to guess a number.
number = int(input("Guess a number, see if you're right: "))

rn = random.randint(1,10)

while number != rn:  # User number is not equal to rn then continue.
    print("Sorry. Try again.")

    if number < rn:  # tells player that the number is too low.
        print("Higher")
        number = int(input("Guess again, see if you're right: "))

    if number > rn:  # Tells the player that the number is too high.
        print("Lower")
        number = int(input("Guess again, see if you're right: "))

    if number == rn:  # User number equals random number break
        print("Well, you got it. Congrats!")
        break
```